# Getting a popOver from a popover for an ios application

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

My scenario is like this.
I have a tableview cell which has a button.If fire it menu will popout like below

[image]

for the above menu popover the source is the button that is appearning extreme right of each cell.

I have another table view called diplayAccounts.
on click of the popover menu's cell (i.e. view hierarchy) the displayAccounts 
View controller needs to be displayed as a popover. My doubt is that what should be the source for it.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
menuTapped(self)
}
```

the method menuTapped is as follows

```
func menuButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HierarchyTableViewController") as! HierarchyTableViewController
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.sourceView = sender as? UIView
    popover.delegate = self
    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

And the error that I'm getting

[image]
Please help me.

Comment: "Now I want to get another popover on click of the viewHierarchy" What did you mean by this?

Comment: I have another table view called diplayAccounts.
on click of the popover menu's cell (i.e. view hierarchy) the displayAccounts View controller needs to be displayed as a popover. My doubt is that what should be the source for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not good idea to present pop over inside another popover(From Apple Mobile Human Interface Guidelines)

The best thing you can do is like

**In pop over view controller class**

- Implement a delegate protocol in the view controller class that displays the list of items as you shown in the attachment.
- Inside that delegate protocol, add a call back method with the params to contain the details of the selected cell.
- Add delegate property in the view controller of the popover class.
- Call the delegate method from the cell selection event.

**In cell class that displays the button from which popover is presented**

(i.e. the cell displaying 44087 and 111 in the picture above)

- Initialise the delegate object before presenting pop over
- Implement the delegate method declared in the delegate protocol to get the selection event.
- Show the other pop over you wanted.

  **UPDATE**

This will be the popover view controller that displays list of items as you shown above

**PopOverWithListItemsViewController.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol PopoverWithListItemsViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didSelectedListItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end

@interface PopOverWithListItemsViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PopoverWithListItemsViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In table view selection event, add the delegate call like

```
NSInteger indexOfSelectedItem =  4;// jus for demo setting index as 4
[self.delegate didSelectedListItemAtIndex:indexOfSelectedItem];
```

**And in the class from which you presenting list popover**, add the following

**Step1**

The class from which you present the pop over should confirm to the delegate like follows

`@interface ViewController () <PopoverWithListItemsViewDelegate> // let ViewController is the class from which you presenting the pop over`

**Step2**

```
// Let this be the cell's button tap event from which you presenting the pop over
- (IBAction)buttonTapEvent:(id)sender
{
  // Presenting pop over sections
  PopOverWithListItemsViewController *listItemsPopOverVC = [[PopOverWithListItemsViewController alloc] init];
  listItemsPopOverVC.delegate = self;
  // pop over presenting with listItemsPopOverVC as popover's view controller
}
```

**Step3**

```
// Delegate method implementation.
- (void)didSelectedListItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
  // Here we get the index of the selected cell in the popover.
  // Present the new popover from here, after customizing the new pop over contents.
}
```

Comment: in the third step, u r telling me to write code for next popover but the difficulty that i find over here is how can i put the button as source here. i dont have the reference of it right @Alex

Comment: The class from which you performing the step 1,2, 3 will be having an outlet reference to the button, right? I think it should be some UITableViewCell class.

Comment: yea,We have it in cellForRowAtIndexPath but in the step-3 , 
    - (void)didSelectedListItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index  method
we don't have it.

Comment: Do you have a custom cell class, that you using from your cellForRowAtIndexPath to create the table view cell?? or you customising UITableViewCell there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113696/discussion-between-ramcharan-reddy-and-alex).